# Como faço pra foto de noite e tarde aparecer no site?

Tags: javascript

```js
function carregar(){
  var msg = window.document.getElementById('msg')
  var img = window.document.getElementById('imagem')
  var data = new Date()
  var hora = data.getHours()
      msg.innerHTML = `Agora são ${hora} horas`
  if (hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
          //BOM DIA!!
          img.setAttribute = '<img.src="fotomanhã.png">'
  } else if (hora >= 12 && hora < 18 ) {
          //BOA TARDE!!
          img.setAttribute= '<img.src="fototarde.png">'
  } else {
          //BOA NOITE!!
          img.setAttribute = '<img.src="fotonoite.png">'
  }

}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O código abaixo pode ajudar:

```js
msg = window.document.getElementById('msg');
img = window.document.getElementById('imagem');
hora = new Date().getHours();

msg.innerHTML = hora < 12 ? "Bom dia" : hora < 18 ? "Boa tarde" : "Boa noite";

foto = hora < 12 ? "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/18/14/40/balcony-1834990__340.jpg" : hora < 18 ? "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/05/14/39/sunset-3726030__340.jpg" : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/06/26/06/52/moon-6365467__340.jpg";

img.src = foto;
```

```html
<h1>
Teste
</h1>

<div id="msg"></div>
<image id="imagem" width="100" heigth="100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/22/17/56/loading-645268_960_720.jpg"></image>
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda! :)